# Getting value from JSON stored as NSString for iOS in xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

I have some JSON stored as an `NSString` and I am trying to convert this to a NSDictionary and get the value of 'EndDate' in my JSON.

I wanted to retrieve 'EndDate' from the JSON but due to the amount of levels i'm not quite sure how I should be achieving it.

Here is the JSON:

```
{ "GetResponse":{ "GetResult":{ "Faults":null, "Response":{ "Asset":{ "AssetParts":{ "@nil":"true" }, "CountryLookupCode":808, "Number”:24234, "Duplicate":"false", "Code":"`123”, "Channel”:”SR”, “Desc”:”Test”, "Number”:123, “Mandate”:{ "@nil":"true" }, “TestTime”:”True”, “Date”:”2010-08-12T19:00:00", “Results”:{ “Details”:[ { "EndDate":"2013-08-13T18:59:59", “Type”:”Taken”, "Item”:”902”, “Level”:”SL”, “Description”:”Timed”, “Group”:1, “Prov”:{ "@nil":"true" }, "StartDate":"2010-08-12T19:00:00" }, { "EndDate":"2013-08-13T18:59:59", “Machine”:”Dated”, “Country”:”UK”, "Code":"CCDD”, “Description”:”Addressed”, “Level”:2, "Provider":{ "@nil":"true" }, "StartDate":"2010-08-12T19:00:00" }, { "EndDate":"2013-08-13T18:59:59", "Type”:”Title”, "ItemNumber”:”1253”, "Service":"NEDD”, “Desc”:”Down”, “Grp”:5, "Provider":{ "@nil":"true" }, "StartDate":"2010-08-12T19:00:00" } ] } } } } } }
```

Here is my code:

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.0.20/test.json"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
        NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
        //End
        NSData *data = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        NSArray *performersArray = [json objectForKey:@"GetResponse"];
        for (NSDictionary *performerDic in performersArray) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [performerDic objectForKey:@"EndDate"]);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Check your json-file.
The `NSArray *performersArray = [json objectForKey:@"GetResponse"];` is wrong. The `[json objectForKey:@"GetResponse"]` - returns a NSDictionary.

Comment: I think, sorry if I am wrong, something is missing with the JSON you gave. Here is a URL that you can check your the data and see how your JSON is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu . Site can't convert your JSON, the reason I'm telling is that.

Comment: `requestReply` is not needed and neither is `data`, just use `requestHandler`. Also `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is almost always a bad idea, `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is almost always better. If you rea=ly want a string from data use: `initWithData:encoding`.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then understand that a JSON "object" maps to an NSDictionary, and a JSON "array" maps to an NSArray.  After decoding the JSON via NSJSONSerialization, take apart the resulting structure one level at a time, NSLogging after each step.  If you make half an effort to actually UNDERSTAND it rather than trying to do it by rote then it's blazingly simple.

Comment: And **use the `error` parm!!**

Comment: Part of the problem is that (likely due to using a word processor to edit the JSON) you have the wrong character for `"` in several places.  Eg, `"Number”:24234,` -- the closing quote is not an ASCII character.  (This is why you should use the `error` parm.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *detailsArray = json[@"GetResponse"][@"GetResult"][@"Response"][@"Asset"][@"Results"][@"Details"];
for (NSDictionary *detailsDict in detailsArray){
    NSLog(@"%@",detailsDict[@"EndDate"]);
}
```

this should work